# an algorithm to find if a FORKED list is circular

Tags: list, algorithm, linked-list, circular-list

a forked list is kind of a linked list that there exists a node (at least) that has two 'next's, next1 and next2. i.e., each node is made up of 3 attributes - value, next1 and next2. for each node apart from at least one, next2 may be None.
I am looking for an algorithm that takes a forked list as an input, it returns True if there's a circle in the list and otherwise returns False.
p.s. we can assume that the list starts and ends like a normal linked list (with only one next) and the node(s) which has 2 'next's is one of the inner nodes.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! To make your question better, it should show some effort - what did you try to solve this problem so far? Also, keep in mind that SO is a programming forum: Are you trying to solve a programming problem, or doing a homework for an algorithms class?

Comment: Check out [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting)

Comment: I'm trying to find a possible algorithm in order to write the code. The problem is, I don't know how to start thinking about the problem, what are the possible situations and so on. If needed, I can attach the python code of the class ForkedList as well.

Answer (score 1):

Treat the "forked tree" as a directed graph and look for **circuits** in the graph, e.g. [Johnson's algorithm](https://www.cs.tufts.edu/comp/150GA/homeworks/hw1/Johnson%2075.PDF)

Comment: Thank you so much this actually helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Treat the "forked tree" as a a set of **dependencies** from an item to directly linked next items. A [Topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) of the items will fail by detecting any circularities.